# Checksum ip packet

Tags: c

Galera gostaria de entender as 4 ultimas linhas  , porque fazer todos esses bitswise?
Código [completo](http://cboard.cprogramming.com/networking-device-communication/41635-ping-program.html).

Segue o código:

```
static int in_cksum(u_short *addr, int len)
{
    register int nleft = len;
    register u_short *w = addr;
    register int sum = 0;
    u_short answer = 0;

    /*
     * Our algorithm is simple, using a 32 bit accumulator (sum), we add
     * sequential 16 bit words to it, and at the end, fold back all the
     * carry bits from the top 16 bits into the lower 16 bits.
     */
    while (nleft > 1)  {
        sum += *w++;
        nleft -= 2;
    }

    /* mop up an odd byte, if necessary */
    if (nleft == 1) {
        *(u_char *)(&answer) = *(u_char *)w ;
        sum += answer;
    }


    sum = (sum >> 16) + (sum & 0xffff); /* add hi 16 to low 16 */
    sum += (sum >> 16);         /* add carry */
    answer = ~sum;              /* truncate to 16 bits */
    return(answer);
}
```

Comment: Acho que seria melhor ter editado a anterior em vez de feito uma pergunta quase igual. Como essa ficou um pouco melhor, talvez seja melhor remover aquela. http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/111161/

Answer (score 0):

Depois dos cálculos iniciais concluídos, a variável `sum` (32 bits) vai ter um valor qualquer.

A primeira expressão (`sum = (sum >> 16) + (sum & 0xffff);`) isola as duas metades de 16 bits desse valor e soma-as, metendo o resultado na variável original

```
bits    31 30 ... 17 16 // sum >> 16
bits  + 15 14 ... 01 00 // sum & 0xffff
      -----------------
bits xx 15 14 ... 01 00 // xx é o carry
```

Nota que a soma destas duas metades terá, no máximo, 17 bits significativos.

A segunda expressao (`sum += (sum >> 16);`) faz (mais ou menos) o mesmo que a primeira. A diferença é que esta expressão não se preocupa com o que fica nos *high* bits.

```
bits    31 30 ... 17 16 15 14 ... 01 00 // sum
bits  +                 31 30 ... 17 16 // sum >> 16
      ---------------------------------
bits xx xx ... xx xx xx 15 14 ... 01 00 // xx é o carry nos high bits
```

Finalmente, a terceira expressao (`answer = ~sum;`) troca os bits calculados e isola os 16 *low* bits porque mete o valor numa variável de tipo `u_short`.

```
answer = ~sum;
// bits de ~sum:   31 30 ... 17 16 15 14 ... 01 00
// bits de answer:                 15 14 ... 01 00
```